# Hooking up specific arrays to UITableViewCell UIImage and UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Not sure if my question title is the most specific, but I'll try to explain:

I have a uitableviewscene which segues to another viewcontroller that displays arrays based on which item the user had selected. The segue works fine, however, I am unsure as to how to link each specific array to a UIImage and UILabel on the new view controller. Below I have provided the code for the view controller. I do not have enough rep to post images of what the app looks like currently. Could someone please advise on how to proceed here?!

**SecondTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *secondImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabel;

@end
```

**SecondTableViewCell.m**

```
#import "SecondTableViewCell.h"

@implementation SecondTableViewCell
@synthesize secondLabel = _secondLabel;
@synthesize secondImage = _secondImage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

**WXMenuTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WXMenu_TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *secondview;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *SecondMenuText;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *SecondMenuImage;

@end
```

**WXMenuTableViewController.m**

```
#import "WXMenu_TableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewCell.h"



@interface WXMenu_TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation WXMenu_TableViewController

@synthesize SecondMenuImage = _SecondMenuImage;
@synthesize SecondMenuText = _SecondMenuText;

//Define array for weather products list
    NSArray *allwx;
    NSArray *allintel;
    NSArray *allfuels;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Define the products list

    allwx = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Daily Weather", @"Fire Potential",
            @"Multi-Media Briefing", @"Sig. Fire Potential",@"Seasonal Outlook", @"Fire Season Broadcast", nil];
    allintel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"New IA", @"Current Fire", nil];
    allfuels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Current Fuels Status",@"Fuel Danger", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Set table size to one section.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //When Root Menu items are clicked on previous VC, specific lists is displayed
    if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Weather"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allwx;
        return [_SecondMenuText count];
        }
    else if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Intelligence"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allintel;
        return [_SecondMenuText count];
        }
    else if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Fuels"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allfuels;
        return [_SecondMenuText count];
    }
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tableID = @"MainCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableID];
    }
    if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Weather"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allwx;
        cell.textLabel.text = [_SecondMenuText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Intelligence"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [allintel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Fuels"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [allfuels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: What isn't working with the code above, or what's happening that shouldn't be happening?

Comment: The segue to the new view controller is working just fine: it populates the new view controller to display tables of an array that is based on the user's selection on the previous scene's table. The problem now is I don't know how to hook up those new tables to a tableviewcell (uilabel and uiimage). I would imagine it is solved with some type of if/else statement but am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, setting your data source array in `numberOfRowsInSection` is a terrible idea. This method can be called often, and you're redundantly setting your data source. If you're going to have a static source based on what appears to be an externally-set string, do this in `viewDidLoad`. This will also greatly simplify your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. (There also doesn't seem to be any need to have `_SecondMenuText` be a `@property` but I'll let that slide)

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Define the products list

    allwx = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Daily Weather", @"Fire Potential", @"Multi-Media Briefing", @"Sig. Fire Potential",@"Seasonal Outlook", @"Fire Season Broadcast", nil];
    allintel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"New IA", @"Current Fire", nil];
    allfuels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Current Fuels Status",@"Fuel Danger", nil];

    if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Weather"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allwx;
    }
    else if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Intelligence"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allintel;
    }
    else if ([_secondview isEqualToString:@"Fuels"]) {
        _SecondMenuText = allfuels;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(_SecondMenuText.count)
        return _SecondMenuText.count;
    return 1;
}
```

You never mention this and aren't currently using them, but I'm assuming that because you posted code for a custom table view cell that you're wanting to use those with your label and image. As for the image, you either need another static set of arrays that are set in the controller (like you did with `allwx`, `allintel`, and `allfuels`) or you need to pass in an array to your property after you create your table view controller, like so:

```
// wherever you create the controller, set it
WXMenuTableViewController *tableController = [[WXMenuTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleNormal];
tableController.SecondMenuImage = anArrayOfImages;
```

I'm going to assume that your images array has the same number of objects as your text array for any given situation.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tableID = @"MainCell"; // make sure this is whatever you set as your reuse ID in your custom cell xib
    SecondTableViewCell *cell = (SecondTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableID];

    if(!cell)
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.secondLabel.text = [_SecondMenuText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.secondImage.image = [_SecondMenuImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this worked great. I genuinely appreciate your time. I'm a meteorologist by trade, hacking through this stuff without much experience. Thanks a million.